# printing according to value distance but considering another column

Tags: sorting, awk

I have this huge table with ~200k lines and columns (tab separated). I'd like to pick them according to the value of this particular column $4 so their values are spaced for at least 100, but also considering the value on column $3. i.e

```
id      tag     xxx    position score
id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
id_2    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3199    1
id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
id_4    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3350    1
id_5    aaaaaaa ccccc   100    1
id_6    aaaaaaa ccccc   500    1
id_7    aaaaaaa ccccc   550    1
id_8    aaaaaaa ccccc   599    1
```

To get something like this:

```
    id      tag     block   position score
    id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
    id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
    id_5    aaaaaaa ccccc   100     1
    id_6    aaaaaaa ccccc   500     1
```

Some time ago @hek2mgl helpedme to filter a huge table according to the distance between values using this code

```
awk 'NR<3; NR==2{pv=$4} NR>2 && ($4-pv>=100){print;pv=$4}' file
```

However, this code doesnt consider the $3 which now I need to consider to avoid creating a new file for each block.. could this be possible, as it's a bit complicated considering that the values in $4 are not consecutive if they dont represent the same block ($3)?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear at least to me how exactly you want $3 to affect the processing. Also, would it be acceptable to incur the cost of sorting the file (by $3 and $4, or vice versa)?

Comment: The values on $3 indicate a group to which the values on $4 correspond. Many groups on $3 and values on $4. The problem is that the values on $4 are not consecutive, meaning that a group could end on 1000 but the other group would start on 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!
Just qualify the previous values with $3.

```
$ awk 'NR<3; NR==2{pv[$3]=$4} NR>2 && ($4-pv[$3]>=100){print;pv[$3]=$4}' file

id      tag     xxx    position score
id_1    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3190    1
id_3    aaaaaaa bbbbb   3300    1
id_5    aaaaaaa ccccc   100    1
id_6    aaaaaaa ccccc   500    1
```

i.e. change `pv` to `pv[$3]`.  You can pipe the output to `column -t` to get better format, or change print to printf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed column size, why not a simple printf ?

```
spc=10;
while read a b c d e; do
        printf '%-'$spc's %-'$spc's %-'$spc's %-'$spc's %-'$spc's\n' $a $b $c $d $e;
done < file
```

`spc` defines the number of spaces between columns

Outputs :

```
id         tag        xxx        position   score     
id_1       aaaaaaa    bbbbb      3190       1         
id_2       aaaaaaa    bbbbb      3199       1         
id_3       aaaaaaa    bbbbb      3300       1         
id_4       aaaaaaa    bbbbb      3350       1         
id_5       aaaaaaa    ccccc      100        1         
id_6       aaaaaaa    ccccc      500        1         
id_7       aaaaaaa    ccccc      550        1         
id_8       aaaaaaa    ccccc      599        1
```